# What fruits, vegetables, raw meats, or spices are naturally blue?

Tags: color, blueberries

So, here's an odd question.

A few years ago, my home ed. teacher told us that she would not eat anything that is colored blue. it's unnatural.

Thinking on this, I confronted her about blueberries. She argued that blueberries are purple. Okay.

What vegetables, fruits, meats, or spices are naturally blue (either before or after preparation)?

<sup>(For all intents and purposes, yes, blueberries are blue)</sup>

Comment: You can't win this one. If she says blueberries are purple then she is already nit-picking to stand by her bizarre conviction.

Comment: @Sobachatina I know. but blue berries can't be the lone example, can they? Besides, this was 5 years ago. not gonna go back just to win that silly conundrum.

Comment: I'm sure even if you brought her a blue heritage carrot she would hold it up to a swatch and declare it to be Indigo not blue.

Comment: I'm not sure this is really a food question, but it is a biology question: [Why are so few foods blue?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/56476).

Comment: [George Carlin asked the same thing years ago.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l04dn8Msm-Y)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Butterfly pea flowers, [corn flower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centaurea_cyanus#Uses), [chicory flowers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicory), [blue mallow flower](https://bluechai.com/shop/complete-blue-tea-set/) and [blue lotus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nymphaea_nouchali#Uses) all have blue flowers and the petals are used to make tea, in salads, or to spice foods (for the color).

[Black goji berries](https://bluechai.com/shop/complete-blue-tea-set/) are also supposed to make a blue tea, so probably have a blue juice.  If blueberries' purple juice disqualifies them, blue juice should qualify the goji berries even if they look very dark when whole.

Blue corn is also an option, as payton B mention - there are [many varieties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_corn) including [hopi blue](https://www.etsy.com/listing/119273335/corn-hopi-blue-corn-seed-beautiful-blue?ga_order=most_relevant&ga_search_type=all&ga_view_type=gallery&ga_search_query=blue%20seeds&ref=sr_gallery_48), [aztec black](https://www.etsy.com/listing/229919118/aztec-black-corn-ancient-heirloom-50?ga_order=most_relevant&ga_search_type=all&ga_view_type=gallery&ga_search_query=blue%20corn&ref=sr_gallery_4) (grinds to blue meal, so blue inside), [santo domingo](https://www.etsy.com/listing/495456140/santo-domingo-blue-corn-seeds?ga_order=most_relevant&ga_search_type=all&ga_view_type=gallery&ga_search_query=blue%20corn&ref=sr_gallery_9), [lenape](https://www.etsy.com/listing/268100501/corn-seed-lenape-blue-corn?ga_order=most_relevant&ga_search_type=all&ga_view_type=gallery&ga_search_query=blue%20corn&ref=sr_gallery_47), or my favorite (and very visibly blue) baby [blue jade](https://www.etsy.com/listing/229765915/baby-blue-jade-corn-25-rare-seeds-non?ga_order=most_relevant&ga_search_type=all&ga_view_type=gallery&ga_search_query=jade%20blue%20corn&ref=sr_gallery_2) corn.

There's also assorted odds and ends like [blue sausage fruit](https://www.etsy.com/listing/224550881/big-sale-blue-sausage-fruitdecaisnea?ga_order=most_relevant&ga_search_type=all&ga_view_type=gallery&ga_search_query=blue%20beans&ref=sr_gallery_41) or [succotash bean](http://www.ebay.com/itm/162271657226), [prickly caterpillar bean](https://www.etsy.com/listing/125734174/prickly-caterpillar-bean-15-seeds?ref=shop_home_active_72), fruit of the [bilberry cactus](https://www.etsy.com/listing/126179683/bilberry-cactus-vivid-blue-15-seeds?ref=shop_home_active_74), a [blue kale](http://www.burpee.com/vegetables/kale/kale-lacinato--prod001950.html), a [blue-green tomato](http://www.rareseeds.com/wagner-blue-green-tomato/) (the blue-reds tend to look black, but they're called blue), couple other [blue](http://www.tradewindsfruit.com/blue-tomatoes/) [tomatoes](http://www.sfgate.com/homeandgarden/article/The-buzz-on-blue-tomatoes-5295725.php), [blue potatoes](https://www.leaf.tv/articles/what-are-blue-potatoes/), the blue carrot Sobachatina mentioned - some heirlooms can get oddly colored, it's fun.

Some of these do tend towards the purplish, but in every case either the inside is blue, the juice or pulp is blue, or there are pictures of truly blue examples as well as purplish ones (probably depending on pH of the soil).

There's also a double handful of blue flowers and berries that are ornamental, but not eaten, and again as much of purpleish ones that have some really blue pigment (in patches or along edges).

Answer (score 2):

Blue corn would be a good example.

Answer (score 2):

A meat that is blue is [lingcod](http://www.npr.org/sections/thesalt/2014/06/17/322920045/red-fish-blue-fish-where-the-fish-flesh-rainbow-comes-from) (about 20% of the time, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lingcod)). The rock/kelp greenling and cabezon also sometimes have blue flesh, though I'm not sure if the cabezon is edible ([source](http://www.npr.org/sections/thesalt/2014/06/17/322920045/red-fish-blue-fish-where-the-fish-flesh-rainbow-comes-from)).

Some chickens and birds lay blue eggs. Now, the yolk and white aren't blue, but the shell is.